# File reading not working for android

Tags: android

I am an android newbie and wrote this code for file handling but for some reason i am always getting back null values from the file. I also tried using readline() but got the same result. Would appreciate any help.

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String file = "test123";
            try 
            {
                OutputStream out =  v.getContext().openFileOutput(file, MODE_PRIVATE);
                InputStream in =  v.getContext().openFileInput(file);
                WriteFile(out);
                String str = ReadFile(in);

                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public static void WriteFile(OutputStream out)
{
    OutputStreamWriter tmp = new OutputStreamWriter(out);

    try 
    {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 10; i++)
        {
            tmp.write(i);
        }
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();            
    }
}

public static String ReadFile(InputStream in)
{
    InputStreamReader tmp = null;
    String str = "";        

    tmp = new InputStreamReader(in);
    BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(tmp);                      

    try 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            str += " " + reader.readLine();             
        }           

    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   

    return str;
}
```

}

Comment: I guess the error is that you use the same file to read from and to write to. Try to use different files.

Comment: i want to read from the file i have already written into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String file = "test123";`
So, the path of your file should be `{root}/test123`
Try defining a path were you can access to see if it has written something. (usually : /mnt/storage/your_file)
Then, you'll be able to determine if the Write/Read process works or not

Note : Take a look at [FileOutputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileOutputStream.html), it already implements lots of useful methods

Comment: so is it not recommended to use openFileOutput()? I am a bit confused because openFileOutput(filename) doesn't like path separators in the input.